# use jQuery to get rid of html

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering how to make the following.

Lets say I have 4 (or more) questions. Every question has 1 or more subquestions and a checkbox. The html would be something like this

```
<div class="question>
    <p>What kind of fruit do you like?</p>
    <div class="subquestions">
        <p>I like bananas</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like apples</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like strawberrys</p><input checkbox>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question>
    <p>What kind of class do you like?</p>
    <div class="subquestions">
        <p>I like math</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like biology</p><input checkbox>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question>
    <p>What kind of sport do you like?</p>
    <div class="subquestions">
        <p>I like football</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like cricket</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like tennis</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like basketball</p><input checkbox>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="question>
    <p>What kind of games do you like?</p>
    <div class="subquestions">
        <p>I like call of duty</p><input checkbox>
        <p>I like battlefield 3</p><input checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the html is repeated 4 times, only the questions and subquestions change so I was wondering if there's a way using jQuery to get rid of the html.

```
<div class="question>
    <p><question_text></p>
    <div class="subquestions">
        <p><subquestion_text></p><input checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking maybe I can make a function in which I have this html mark up and then use variables to put in the data. But I'm still learning a lot about jQuery so I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: I see what you're asking...I think. You want to use jQuery to replicate the HTML, so that you only have to write it once, correct?

Comment: Trying to reinvent templating, maybe?

Comment: honestly, having the repeated html is not that bad

Comment: It's not a good idea to do this with javascript. You should look at a server side scripting language, like php.

Comment: @Vic this is just an example. My actual html is a lot bigger and copy/pasting everything makes the chances for mistakes bigger and the code harder to see.

Comment: @Leigh that is what I'm trying to do yes, but it would nee to have variables because every question is different and has different values.

Comment: @PabloMescher it's not possible to use php for this situation at the moment.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Are these questions stored somewhere with the subquestions in DB?

Comment: @mabus44 the questions are now stored in the html and not in a database or something like that.

Comment: if you don't have access to the server side, then maybe you can save the questions into a json/xml file and use javascript to load that file and display the html

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dummy for a question and subquestion (not more like "answer"?) like this

```
var questionDummy = '<div class="question">'
                  + '<p>[question]</p>'
                  + '<div class="subquestions">[subquestions]</div>'
                  + '</div>',
    subquestionDummy = '<p>[label]</p><input checkbox>';
```

Next step is to use those dummys. For performance reasons we will first prepare them and output them all at once. Say you have arrays containing your questions and everything (the structure can be seen from the code -- this is just an example):

```
var questions = new Array(yourQuestions.length);
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var subquestions = new Array(yourQuestions[i].subquestions.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < subquestions.length; j++) {
        subquestions[j] = subquestionDummy.replace('[label]', yourQuestions[i].subquestions[j].label);
    }

    questions[i] = questionDummy
        .replace('[question]', yourQuestions[i].question)
        .replace('[subquestions]', subquestions.join(''));
}
```

Now you can output it. If you want to use jQuery (which only makes sense if you use it anyway -- otherwise do it with pure JavaScript; no need to load such a big library for this reason only!), this is a way:

```
$('#someDivThatWrapsAllQuestions').html(questions.join(''));
```

Comment: By the way: I personally disagree on calling this bad practice because JS might be disabled. Yes, server-side makes it "safer" in the sense that it'll work for definitely everyone ... but truth be told: You don't enable JavaScript these days, you can't use half the internet. I don't care for people not enabling standard web technology when surfing. Again, this is my personal view on this.

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, this is basic templating. Of course there are libraries for this that are much better. I wanted to give an insight on how a simple one could work (I actually use this kind of basic templating), for educational purposes ... but it really doesn't have anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explenation but I guess the question is just something I can't solve at this moment since your code is (too) hard too understand for me.

Comment: So it's a challenge to learn. Read up on loops and arrays, that's all it is -- and both you will need in any programming language. After that, go through the code step by step. It's really fairly simple, actually. Just an opportunity to learn!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem at work. I solved it by throwing the questions and answers into a JSON format which is stored in the DB like so:

```
QuestionTable
=====================================
QuestionID  QuestionField   JSONField
```

The JSON includes all the default properties. In your case, your first question would be formatted like so (it's kinda long, but I hope it gets the idea across):

```
var objToStringify = {
    "question": "What kind of fruit do you like?",
    "answers": [
        {
            "label": "I like bananas",
            "type": "input",
            "attributes": {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "value": "bananas"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "I like apples",
            "type": "input",
            "attributes": {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "value": "apples"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "I like strawberries",
            "type": "input",
            "attributes": {
                "type": "checkbox",
                "value": "strawberries"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Then the jQuery to build the question looks like this:

```
var addQuestion = function addQuestion(parsedJSON) {
    var div = $('<div />'),
        p = $('<p />'),
        label = $('<label />'),
        q = div.clone().addClass('question'),
        a = div.clone().addClass('subquestions'),
        ans = {},
        i = 0;
    q.append(p.clone().text(parsedJSON.question));
    if (parsedJSON.answers) {
        for (i = 0; i < parsedJSON.answers; i += 1) {
            ans = parsedJSON.answers[i];
            a.append(
                p.clone().append(
                    label.clone().text(ans.label)
                ).append(
                    $(document.createElement(ans.type)).attr(ans.attributes)
                )
            );
        }
    }
    q.append(a);
    $('#someDOMElement').append(q);
};
```

This is one way to template, there are others. There are, in fact, libraries that exist to deal with this (e.g., [Moustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/)).

Also, there is the concern that your users won't be able to take your survey/quiz if they have disabled JavaScript. I can get away with what I did because it's deployed in a corporate environment where users cannot disable JavaScript because of Group Policy. If you're not in a similar situation, you may want to consider a server-side language to generate your HTML instead. Both PHP and ASP.Net excel at this (and I'm sure others do as well, but these are the two I have experience with).

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practice, because if the client has JavaScript disabled, the code will fail to render.

Instead, research using a back end language like [PHP](http://php.net)

Comment: It's not for a big website. I'm trying to create something like a questionlist that I can use on my laptop and that I can show to some students. Nothing too fancy and I'm trying to understand jQuery better so I was hoping I could create or at least understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this using jQuery or JavaScript. But if you decide to do this using jQuery or JavaScript, figure out how much time you're saving versus everything it will "cost" you on the front end: putting the processing burden on your users' respective clients and machines, some of which may be underpowered; making sure your code is usable by mobile devices; keeping jQuery updated so that it continues to work even three years from now; making sure that it displays the same across all browsers...and that doesn't even touch accessibility concerns.

Which is going to be the overall smartest solution for you? To me, it seems like this isn't really a savings, it's just overengineering for the sake of playing with code-toys. But I may not understand all the parameters of your project. (And sometimes, playing with code-toys is payoff enough, especially if it's for a hobby rather than a customer-serving site or project :) )